# Change class for a VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to change the class of a component in VueJS after 2.5 seconds and I'm using this code:

```
const Header = {
  template: `<header :class=hclass v-html="header"></header>`,
  data () {
   return {
     hclass: 'off'
   }
  },
  methods: {
    changeVisibility () {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        this.hclass = 'on'
        console.log('Change to on!', this.hclass)
      }, 2500)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    header () {
      this.changeVisibility()
      return store.state.header
    }
  }
}
```

While I see it in the console it says 'Change to on!', it never actually updates my class with 'on'!

Comment: context of function has been changed to window,this.hclass means window.hclass,not vm.hclass.you may use arrow functions,or use function(){}.bind(this),

Comment: just use a standard way https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

template: `<header :class="{ 'dynamicClass': hclass }" v-html="header"></header>`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing to the right direction!

```
methods: {
    changeVisibility () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.hclass = true
            console.log('Change to on!', this.hclass)
        }.bind(this), 5000)
    }
}
```